# How to check if all lines in a 2d int array have the same length?

Tags: java, arrays

If I have a 1D array, I can easily check the length of the row with with `a.length`. In a 2D array, I can check the length of all columns with something like this

```
int[][] a = {{5,3,4,6,7,8,9,1,2},
             {6,7,2,1,9,5,3,4,8},
             {1,9,8,3,4,2,5,6,7},
             {8,5,9,7,6,1,4,2,3},
             {4,2,6,8,5,3,7,9,1},
             {7,1,3,9,2,4,8,5,6},
             {9,6,1,5,3,7,2,8,4},
             {2,8,7,4,1,9,6,3,5}};
for (int k = 0; k < a.length; k++) {
    if (a[k].length != 9) return false
}
```

I am not even sure if that is correct. How can I check the different rows? When I have a 4x4 matrix, and the last row only contains 3 values instead of 4, how can I find that out?

Comment: But into the ```array[3][3]=0``` takes a place, if ```array[0][3]....array[2][3]!=0```.

Comment: It's unclear what you want to check, the same length or the same number of values?  Your code says one thing but the text below another thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Semicolon missing after false.)* Your code is correct. If you get passed an `int[][] a` of unknown size:

```
boolean isRectangularMatrix(int[][] a) {
    int columnCount = 0; // Maybe interesting too.
    boolean rectangular = true;
    if (a.length != 0) {
        columnCount = a[0].length;
        for (int k = 1; k < a.length; k++) {
            if (a[k].length != columnCount) {
                //return false; // Or:
                rectangular = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return rectangular;
}

boolean isSquareMatrix(int[][] a) {
    int columnCount = 0; // Maybe interesting too.
    boolean square = true;
    if (a.length != 0) {
        columnCount = a[0].length;
        if (a.length != columnCount) {
            square = false;
        } else {
            for (int k = 1; k < a.length; k++) {
                if (a[k].length != columnCount) {
                    //return false; // Or:
                    square = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return square;
}
```

You do not need a check if the array is created correspondingly:

```
int[][] a = new int[M][N];
```

Comment: Thanks but unofrtunately that doesn't fully work either. I get true for a 8 row x 9 columns matrix. `int[][] numbers2 = {{5,3,4,6,7,8,9,1,2}, {6,7,2,1,9,5,3,4,8}, {1,9,8,3,4,2,5,6,7}, {8,5,9,7,6,1,4,2,3}, {4,2,6,8,5,3,7,9,1}, 
   {7,1,3,9,2,4,8,5,6}, {9,6,1,5,3,7,2,8,4}, {2,8,7,4,1,9,6,3,5}};`

Comment: @DaveTwickenham _I get true for a 8 row x 9 columns matrix_ That's because it is true. Do you think it should be false? If you do then why?

Comment: If you want _square_ matrices you have to check `a.length == a[0].length` too.  Added